# How to get the released button inside MouseReleaseEvent in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qmouseevent

In `MouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *e)`, is there a way to know which button was released without using a new variable ? I mean something like in the `MousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *e)` with `e.buttons()`.
I tried `e.buttons()` in the releaseEvent it's not working (which is logical).

Comment: " I tried e.buttons() in the releaseEvent" can you please show this code, then we can point out any possible error here? Checking the event buttons is what you should be doing.

Comment: When a button is pressed you store the button in a vector then you check on the release event which buttons are still pressed. The one which isn't was released.

Comment: @a_guest thanks for your answer, but as I said, I'm looking for a way to do it without using a new variable.

Comment: @Merlin069 There is no button pressed on the releaseEvent so the event->buttons() is equal to 0

Comment: Don't confuse `button()` with `buttons()`

Comment: @user3883676, Correct. I have explained this in the answer I have provided.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`e` is already a variable. Just use:

```
void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *e)
{
  if (e->button() == Qt::LeftButton)    // Left button...
  {
    // Do something related to the left button
  }
  else if (e->button() == Qt::RightButton)   // Right button...
  {
    // Do something related to the right button
  }
  else if (e->button() == Qt::MidButton)   // Middle button...
  {
    // Do something related to the middle button
  }
}
```

A `switch` statement also works. I prefer the series of `if -- else if` because they make it easier to handle evente modifiers, i.e., `e->modifiers()` in order to check for alt or control clicks. The series of if's is short enough not to create any burden on the program.

EDIT: Note that you should use the `button()` function, not its plural `buttons()` version. See the explanation in @Merlin069 answer.

Comment: you don't understand, I thank you though for the answer. I already know that e is a variable, that's why i said "new variable". This code works when it's the `MousePressEvent` because there is a button pressed, but on release there is no button pressed so e->button() doesn't have a value.

Comment: The above code works. I use it in all my mouse button handling. The value of e is the button which was just released... Note that I am using button(), not buttons()...

Comment: Worth noting: it may get tricky with left-handed mouse. Left button may become right

Comment: Sorry, my bad, the debug mode doesn't enter the `if` bloc because it contains only a declaration of a variable, It looked like it wasn't getting on it.

Comment: @user3883676 I don't know what to say. I just tested and it works fine. There is a `{` missing just after the `if` bloc in your posted code.

Comment: @rpsml My bad, look at the precedent comment

Answer (score 11):

The problem in the posted code is this: -

```
if(e->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton)
```

As the [Qt documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmouseevent.html#buttons) states for the release event: -

> **...  For mouse release events this excludes the button that caused the event.**

The buttons() function will return the current state of the buttons, so since this is a release event, the code will return false, as it's no longer pressed.

However, the [documentation for the button() function](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmouseevent.html#button) states:-

> **Returns the button that caused the event.**

So you can use the [button()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmouseevent.html#button) function here.